# Clang binaries for 32-bit Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, linux, vim, clang, youcompleteme

I need the llvm Clang binaries for 32bit Ubuntu. On official website i found only x32-64 latest versions of Clang. My question is why? I'm newbie in this, but i want to make my vim plugin "YouCompleteMe" to work with C-family Semantic Completion.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: First of all, you can install clang from the ubuntu repositories, using e.g. `sudo apt-get install clang`, or `sudo apt-get install clang-3.6`. If you want to modify clang or link with libclang or something, you probably want to build clang from source, which you can also do, although the build takes a while.

Comment: apt-get do that for me! thank you so much! =)